# How to allow SSH server to accept inbound traffic from 2 TCP ports?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

## Brief

Allow the following **TCP port** numbers on **SSH** server

- `22`
- `2222`

### Premises

1. The machine uses an **Amazon Linux AMI** distribution
2. The SSH installation is based on an **SELinux system**

### Details

By default, SSH uses TCP port `22`. Is it possible to allow the SSH server to accept inbound traffic from TCP port `2222`? If so... How?

I looked at the SSH's config file...

#### `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
...
# If you want to change the port on a SELinux system, you have to tell
# SELinux about this change.
# semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp #PORTNUMBER
#
#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::
...
```

It tells that I should use `semanage` to configure this section instead of overwriting the said file.

How to use `semanage` to allow the SSH server to accept inbound traffic from 2 TCP port numbers mentioned above? Also both at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

This comment means that you must do *both*.

You must specify all of the desired `Port`s in `sshd_config`, and you must also run `semanage` as shown if you wish to add any ports other than 22.

For example:

```
Port 22
Port 2222
```

Then you would run `semanage`:

```
semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp 2222
```

After doing both of these, it is safe to restart OpenSSH.

```
systemctl restart sshd
```

Comment: I am a little reluctant of forcefully editing the configuration file. You mentioned I should do both, does that mean I really need to uncomment the line that says `#Port 22` and make it `Port 22`, then add another line `Port 2222`. -- before I do `semanage` stuffs and so on --

Will the semanage not enough? **Thanks**

Comment: @AbelMelquiadesCallejo Yes, you must edit the file, uncomment `Port 22` and add in another line `Port 2222`. Running `semanage` only tells SELinux to _allow_ sshd to bind to the port. It does not actually configure sshd to do so. Editing `sshd_config` does that.

Comment: I tried this answer and the weird thing is that at first it told of using `semanage` but when I issued `which semanage`, it turns out it was not installed after all. Also for **Amazon Linux AMI**s, the right way to restart SSH is `/etc/init.d/sshd restart` **Thanks again**

Comment: Ah, you are using old Amazon Linux, and not Amazon Linux 2.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to allow the SSH server to accept inbound traffic from TCP port 2222? If so... How?

It is as simple as adding (additional to the default implied 22) 
`Port` directives in your `sshd_config` file

```
Port 22
Port 2222
```

With regards to the SELinux related command, that is usually only relevant on Red Hat related distributions such as RHEL, Fedora and CentOS

And

```
# semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp 2222
```

Will add 2222 as a valid port for ssh to the ssh policy on the server running sshd

Comment: The weird thing is that at first it told of using `semanage` but when I issued `which semanage`, it turns out it was not installed after all.